# Variation of Pell's equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is it possible to find all integer solutions of the Diophantine equation
$$
2x^{2} - 3y^{2} = 5
$$
I think we have to use $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$ somewhere, but I don't know how to use units of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})}$.

---

I just found a way to find solutions, and I think these are all: 
If $2x^{2} - 3y^{2} = 5$ and $z^{2} - 6w^{2} = 1$, then we have 
$$
2(xz + 3yw)^{2} - 3(yz + 2xw)^{2} = (2x^{2} - 3y^{2})(z^{2} - 6w^{2}) = 5
$$
which follows from $N(\sqrt{2}x + \sqrt{3}y) = 5$ and $N(z - \sqrt{6}y) = 1$. Here the norm map $N$ is $N:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})\to \mathbb{Q}$. 
Since we know a solution for the original equation $(x, y) = (2, 1)$ and the second equation $(5, 2)$, and those are all since "quotient" of two solutions will be a unit in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})}$, which is generated by the fundamental unit $5 + 2\sqrt{6}$ and $-1$.

Comment: Hint: Consider $(2x)^2 - 6y^2 = 10$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form $f(X,Y) = 2X^2-3Y^2$ is a primitive integral indefinite binary quadratic form. The stabilizer of the action of the modular group $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbf{Z})$  is generated by the matrix $W = \begin{pmatrix} 5&6\\4&5\end{pmatrix}$ . Therefore, for any integer $n$, the pair $W^n\begin{pmatrix} 2\\1\end{pmatrix}$ is a solution to your equation.
In general, when one begins with a primitive integral indefinite binary quadratic form and wants to solve the equation $f = m$ for some integer $m$, if there is one solution to this equation, then there are infinitely many such solutions. What one does is to compute a generator of the stabilizer (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$) and use this generator along with a known solution to produce infinitely many solutions.
There is a software -- still being developed -- but needs some pre-reading.
Here are relevant links:

software : http://math.gsu.edu.tr/azeytin/infomod/node/3

book : Buchmann & Vollmer, Binary quadratic forms

article : http://math.gsu.edu.tr/azeytin/pdfs/bqf.pdf

Comment: Nice article. In order to find all integer solutions, which appears to be the question, we must add the orbit of $x=2,y=-1,$ same as the orbit of $x=4,y=3.$

Comment: I left a part answer. About the group, I don't see any book that emphasizes that the generator matrix becomes visible in Conway's topograph diagram if we put in enough detail.

Comment: You are right about the complete set of solutions. 
For the remark concerning the relationship between topograph, there is another article, which is directly related to the solution of the mentioned problem here:
http://math.gsu.edu.tr/azeytin/pdfs/reduction.pdf

Comment: Thank you, Ayberk

Answer (score 1):

ADDED: for your question $2x^2 - 3 y^2 = 5,$ we get two orbits, each can be made into a linear recursion by Cayley-Hamilton:
$$ x= 2, 16, 158, 1564, 15482, ... $$
$$ y = 1, 13, 129, 1277, 12641, ...     $$
with
$$ x_{n+2} = 10 x_{n+1} - x_n , $$
$$ y_{n+2} = 10 y_{n+1} - y_n . $$

The second orbit begins
$$ x= 4, 38, 376, 3722, 36844, ... $$
$$ y = 3, 31, 307, 3039, 30083, ...     $$
with
$$ x_{n+2} = 10 x_{n+1} - x_n , $$
$$ y_{n+2} = 10 y_{n+1} - y_n . $$

ORIGINAL:Well, I don't have a diagram for $2x^2 - 3 y^2$ ready, maybe i could do that later. I do have one for $3 x^2 - 2 y^2,$ and you may read what you require as $3x^2 - 2 y^2 = -5$ but then switch the variables.

Note that the generator matrix for the oriented automorphism group is visible in the pair regions highlighted with asterisks * above and below, where the original form values 3,-2 are repeated.  In [Weissman's recent book](https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-105/), he would say that I draw both the domain topograph and the range topograph together. The domain is the green column vectors, the range is the pink values.

[image]